# What are the risks of improvising to use a nearby embedded metal as a local electrical ground?

Tags: grounding

I'm in India where domestic supply is 250V 50cps 1ph.

My question is similar to [Why does my new floodlight trip the circuit breaker?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/140409/why-does-my-new-floodlight-trip-the-circuit-breaker)?

In my case the supply does not have a ground to this particular outlet. There is however an old rusted iron angle in the ground approx 10 feet away. The angle goes perhaps a metre deep into midly sticky soil.

What are the risks of improvising to use this iron angle as an electrical ground?

Comment: You know you're improvising and you know it's a bad idea or you wouldn't be asking the question. Just don't. Spend the extra money to do it right - it's guaranteed to be cheaper than having someone die.

Comment: I  won't do it. The temptation is there though

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please be sure to give a check-mark to the answer that's helped you the most (or write up and check mark your own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Doesn't work at all.

A piece of metal embedded in the earth is only good for returning *natural* electricity sources - lightning and ESD. This works because those sources are *extremely* high voltage, so they are able to push through the high resistance dirt.

If you have an electrical fault, you need to return human-generated electricity. For that you need a ground wire.  You can't use dirt as a substitute for a copper (or aluminum) wire.  It just doesn't work. 230V doesn't have nearly enough force to push through dirt.

Comment: 240V through a good ground electrode can pass enough current to trip a RCD and such systems (known by the IEC as TT systems) are legitimately used. You still shouldn't go installing an electode without testing it though.

Comment: @PeterGreen -- India's TN, by and large, though -- TT should only be used where regulations call for it due to it requiring mandatory RCD protection

Comment: The supply line in from the pole is just two wired. I may be in a TT. Perhaps a century ago,  when it was built, TT was the way to go?

Comment: @Everyone it is typical for the supply from the pole to not have ground.  You are supposed to locally derive ground.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking there are two main types of earthing system (there are also some others that are only used in specialised situations).

In a TN system the customer's earth is connected to the Neutral and the whole system is connected to the general mass of the earth in one or more places , this provides a low-impedance path for ground faults. TN systems can be divided into three subtypes, in a TN-S system the earth and neutral are kept seperate and only interconnected at a single point. In a TN-C system (now banned in most places) they are combined throughout the system. In a TN-C-S system they are combined in some but not all of the system (commonly they are combined in the suppliers wiring but not in the customer's wiring).

In a TT system the customer's earth and the supply neutral are seperately connected to the general mass of the earth. The issue with TT systems is that the earth fault loop impedance is usually pretty high. So TT systems nearly always have to rely on a RCD for earth fault detection.

Which systems are legal varies between countries, I have no idea what the rules in India are.

In addition to earthing there is also a concept of bonding, the aim of bonding is to ensure that different metal objects that someone can touch are at the same potential, even if the earthing system or the general mass of the earth has fault currents flowing through it. At least in the UK incoming metal water and gas pipes (and occasionally other things but these are by far the most common) are bonded to the electrical earthing system for this purpose.

Using a local earth then has two potential dangers.

1. It won't be a very good earth, it will almost certainly not be good enough for use without a RCD, it may or may not be good enough to use with a RCD, you can't be sure without testing it.
2. It won't be bonded to all the other earthed metalwork, so during a fault there could be a significant potential between your new earth and existing earths. Depending on how close together metalwork connected to different earthing systems is this could pose a hazard.

Comment: TT is a great way to set up a voltage gradient, which can kill somebody if a wire fence is involved...

Answer (score 1):

The risks are that you won't have a proper ground and won't have the protection a ground provides. The fact that the angle iron is old and rusted proves my point. Normal ground rods are made of copper, galvanized steel and numerous other materials base on their ability to conduct and not corrode. The rust will prevent you from getting a good connection. even if you clean it off, the rust will return. Only being a metre deep will also be a problem because it's just not deep enough and the sticky soil will just promote more rust. Any chance you can add a ground in the existing conduit (if it's conduit)?

Comment: Afraid not. I can run a galvanized wire back to a deeper iron or GI waterpipe tho. The angle mentioned is approaching 80y and still stout.